# Bugs in custom ListView while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

In myadapter.java I have following code:

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
  View view=null;
  if(convertView!=null)view=convertView;else view=newView(context,parent);
  HashMap<String,String> d=new HashMap<String,String>();
  d=data.get(position);
  String _r=d.get("r");
  String out=d.get("out");
  Typeface mf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/mf.ttf");
  TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.c_n);
  txt.setText(_r);
  txt.setTypeface(mf);
  if(out.equals("yes") && !d.get("sid").equals("-1")) {
    ImageView imag=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    imag.setVisibility(imag.VISIBLE);//This fires sometimes while scroll, while
    //I scroll & where I don't need it.
    //view.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_c));
    //^ same as setVisibility.
  }
  ...
  return view;
}
```

When I start my app, this list is OK. But, while I scroll, `imag.setVisibility(imag.VISIBLE);` fires sometimes where I don't need it, like listview generates every scroll event. Some ImageViews become visible, that weren't at apps start.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `convertView` and the way it is used for re-cycling existing views.

Example - suppose your list adapter has 20 items but the `ListView` can only display 5 on the screen. Those 5 list item 'views' will be re-cycled by being passed as the `convertView` parameter when the `ListView` is scrolled.

Once you set the visibility of the `ImageView`, it will remain set in the `convertView`. In other words you need to set it to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` if you don't want it visible...

```
ImageView imag=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
if (d.get("ms").equals("yes") && !d.get("sid").equals("-1")) {
    imag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
    imag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Or use View.GONE depending on what you need
```

Comment: And why scrolling is so laggy? :)

Comment: Is there way to say to Android to keep this list in memory?

Comment: If the scrolling is laggy it will be to do with whatever else you are doing in `getView` (for example where you show `...`). When you say about keeping the list in memory if you mean creating all views (including those off screen), you could do it by pre-creating all views but it would be a massive waste of resources. `ListView` is very efficient precisely because it recycles views in the way it does - you just need to make sure your `getView` method is efficient and you make use of `convertView` correctly.

Comment: updated. I only set fontface, text, work with hashmap. There isn't 2 values in hashmap. Actually, 9, but half of them do almost the same work.

Comment: I'd like to ask again: how to say to android to keep list items in memory? (due to some reasons, I think it'd be better in my case, I'd like to try)

Comment: Sorry but your original question was about your `ImageView` showing up when it shouldn't...which I answered and either solves this problem or not. I don't have time to go through a general fault-finding session on the rest of your code and that's not how stackoverflow is meant to work anyway.